# RegLoadKey to a hive file from within a Shadow copy

Tags: c, windows, registry, backup, shadow-copy

I'm creating a shadow copy and I want to mount a registry hive from that shadow copy using `RegLoadKey()` so I go over its content using the normal registry functions.
This usually works well except in certain machines where it doesn't work at all.

I create the shadow copy and get its mount point - something like
`\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy8`
I then call

```
RegLoadKeyW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy8\Windows\System32\config\SOFTWARE", "mntpoint");
```

This call returns `1009 - The configuration registry database is corrupt.`

If I use `CreateFileW()` I can open this file successfully using that path so it is definitely there.

I've made sure that the shadow copy is created with the registry writer so I don't think that's the issue.
There's no difference if I create the shadow copy and try this after a reboot.
This only happens on some machines. on most it works just fine. I'm not sure what differentiates the machines it doesn't work on.
The machine is a windows 2008 64-bit.

Comment: To clarify, this works consistently on some machines and fails consistently on others?  Any common factors you can identify?

Comment: Yes, both are consistent. As mentioned, "I'm not sure what differentiates the machines it doesn't work on"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that to use `RegLoadKeyW()` The loaded hive needs to be somewhere writable. Since the shadow copy is read-only, it failed.
When I copied the mounted file outside the shadow copy it worked fine.

Comment: Your solution cannot ever match your problem description.
You never mentioned the images where moved and/or changed their r/w status on "some" cases.

Answer (score -3):

Are you loading on the same machine where you created the shadow copy?

One of the [RegLoadKeyW()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) remarks says:

> There are two registry hive file formats. Registry hives created on current operating systems typically cannot be loaded by earlier ones.

Comment: Come to think of it, that implies that upgraded operating systems might use the earlier registry format, or worse, a mixture of formats.  @shoosh, is it possible that the affected machines were upgraded from a previous version of the OS?

Comment: No, this is a vanilla, freshly installed machine